Set up a proxy for ingoing and outgoing traffic on Mac OS X
I'm trying to duplicate some behavior of iptables on a Mac. I have seen some people recommend pf but I am willing to use whatever to get this working.
The idea is to redirect incoming traffic on port  to  and send traffic back out to the original destination. With iptables, this looks like:
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport <PORT1> -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:<PORT2>

sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport <PORT2> -j DNAT --to-destination :<PORT1>

Any ideas? Thanks!
